# Secure way to access PHP variables with Ajax - Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using PHP **unique ID & MD5** functions in my PHP code to generate **securely** unique IDs for an affiliate system.

I want to show that unique ID from the php file to the client when the form is submitted. So i have to make `$unid` variable  from the `sendemail.php` available in the `Sendemail.js`.

So  my questions are:

> **1) How Can i Access a variable from PHP in Javascript?
>
>    2) How Can that variable be transferred securely?**

**Sendemail.php**

```
<?php $unid= md5(uniqid());?>
```

**Sendemail.js**

```
 $("#affiliate-form").submit(function( event ) {
 var name= $("#name").val();
 var surname= $("#surname").val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "sendemail.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                  Name:name, 
                  Surname:surname,
                  })//end ajax
        .done(function(data){
                     $('#my-form').append("Message sent! Your encoded ID is:");

                   }); //end done fn                   
                   });//end submit event
```

Comment: MD5 is easily crackable and not suitable for anything security-related anymore.

Comment: Use something like `echo json_encode( [ "unid" => $unid ] );`

Comment: Also use (at least) something like SHA-1.

Comment: For your questions - 1) use `echo` to output your data. Use `json_encode` to encode it as JSON, since that's what you told your ajax to expect. It will be available as the `data` variable in your JS "done" function. 2) use HTTPS to securely transfer the data to the browser.

Comment: P.S. Since you're handling a form "submit" event with jQuery, then `var name= $("#name").val();
 var surname= $("#surname").val();` is almost certainly redundant, assuming these are form field elements with "name" attributes. Just do `data: $(this).serialize()` instead, and jQuery will do the rest. Then you don't even have to change it if your form gets more fields in future. See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: good recommendation how can i do this with data exactly?

Comment: okay i did it!! I used `echo json_encode(array('asd'=>$unid));` then `data.asd` to print it in js

Comment: USE A SALT !!!!

Comment: `$password = uniqid();
 $salt = uniqid();
 $unid = md5($password.'+X_!@{'.$salt);` is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

Return the PHP data as json using `json_encode()` and read it from your javascript code as you would a normal object